# Proof of tangent-secant theorem by similar triangles

Tags: solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line, power-of-the-point

There was a Finnish matriculation examination there was the following question:

Consider a circle and a point $P$ outside the circle. From the point $P$ draw two lines such that each of the line intersects the circle twice, at the points $A,B,C,D$ where $P, A, B$ are collinear as well as $P, C, D$ are collinear. (The original link is http://www.mafyvalmennus.fi/images/uploads/pmyo_s14.pdf problem 14, but as of 2023 this has gone dead and there is no Internet Archive image.)

a) Prove that the triangles $PCB$ and $PAD$ are similar.

b) Prove that $PA\cdot PB=PC\cdot PD$.

c) Consider the special case $A=B$. Prove that in this case $(PA)^2=PC\cdot PD$.

d) Prove using a)-c) Pythagorean theorem.

[image: intersecting secants theorem and tangent-secant theorem]

Is this solution I found on the net valid for c)?

Triangles $PAD$ and $PCA$ has still one common angle $APD$. By the inscribed angle theorem, the
inscribed angles $PAC$ and $PDA$ corresponding the same arc are equal so triangles $PAD$ and $PCA$
has two equal angles, and they are similar. Therefore, $PA/PD=PC/PA$ so $(PA)^2=PC\cdot PD$.

What makes me wonder is that can we use the inscribed angle theorem as $P$ is outside the circle. Is
this proof valid?

Comment: It must be "By the inscribed angle theorem, the inscribed angles **PBC** and PDA..." And yes: you can use the inscribed angle theorem no matter where P is since you're looking at angles on the circle (A,B,C,D are on the circle)!

Comment: I think @Timbuc's comment is misleading here, since the query is about part (c) of the question, not about part (a), so point B has now been merged into point A. In other words we are proving the [tangent-secant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent–secant_theorem), not the [intersecting secants theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_secants_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

Inscribed angle theorem is for angles which are in the interior of a circle, however it is not important for this problem, since we can consider this case, which $PA$ is tangent to the circle, as a limit case of interior angle theorem. For understanding the problem better, consider the previous case, in which $A$ and $B$ do not coincide with each other. In that case we have:

$\measuredangle{PAC}=\pi-\measuredangle{BAC}=\pi-\frac{1}{2}\widetilde{BDC}=\frac{2\pi-\widetilde{BDC}}{2}=\frac{\widetilde{BAC}}{2}$

in which by "$\thicksim$" we mean "arc".

Now we take the limit of the above relation as $B\rightarrow A$.

$\lim_{B\rightarrow A} \measuredangle{PAC}=\lim_{B\rightarrow A} \frac{\widetilde{BAC}}{2}=\frac{\widetilde{AC}}{2}$.

As $\measuredangle{ADP}=\frac{\widetilde{AC}}{2}$, we can claim that in this case that $\overline{PA}$ is tangent to the circle, $\measuredangle{PAC}=\measuredangle{ADP}$, and as $\measuredangle{ADP}$ is common between both triangles $PAC$ and $PAD$, hence those triangles are similar.

Comment: (+1) I think at the end "$\measuredangle{ADP}$ is common between both triangles $PAC$ and $PAD$" should be corrected to "$\measuredangle{APD}$ is common"?

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning this result is often called the "alternate segment theorem", and I think if the original proof had quoted it under that name then the OP wouldn't have been so unsure of its validity. Indeed Wikipedia's article on the [tangent-secant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent–secant_theorem) calls it by that name, though it's presented in the [inscribed angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Corollary) article as an nameless corollary.